# SharePoint - enable/disable webpart on page via code

Tags: web-parts

Is it possible to activate and deactivate a webpart on a page via code?

I want to use the "Current User" webpart on a page but for it to become activated only when the use clicks a button, and then for it to be deactivated again when they click another button. Is this possible?

I could have two versions of the page, one with and one without the current user webaprt and have a button that flicks back and forth between the two pages, but as the page is quite complex, I don't want to have to maintain two instances of it.